# Test method exception:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Test method  exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element  in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put your client endpoints in the app.config file of your test project as well.